# regex pattern to match current directory in dir output

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

I try to extract the creation date of a specific directory from the output produced by the `dir` command in Windows.

Example:

`dir c:\folder\Myfolder\ /T:C /A:D`

Output:

```
22-11-2013  15:09    <DIR>          .
22-11-2013  15:09    <DIR>          ..
21-03-2015  14:32    <DIR>          Folder1
12-09-2014  11:03    <DIR>          Folder2
18-10-2016  13:29    <DIR>          Folder3
```

I tried to pipe the output to `findstr` in order to use a regular expression. But `dir c:\folder\Myfolder\ /T:C /A:D | findstr \r "\."` shows both the `.` and `..` lines.

What I need is the date and time of `Myfolder` (i.e. line with the single `.`) in order to create a timestamp for this folder.

Answer (score 3):

For the last write time, there is not need for the pipe to `findstr`. The same information can be retrieved as

```
for /d %%a in ("c:\folder\Myfolder") do echo %%~ta
```

Use the `~t` modifier of the `for` replaceable parameter to retrieve the timestamp of the folder.

But this method can not be used to retrieve the folder creation time (as Magoo comments). To retrieve it you will need to maintain your original approach

```
dir /tc /ad "c:\folder\Myfolder\.?" | findstr /e /c:" \."
```

(the `.?` is just to shorten the list to be filtered by `findstr` and the enumeration time in `dir`)

Or you can use `wmic` (in this case, it is necessary to change the folder naming format, doubling backslashes)

```
wmic fsdir where name="c:\\folder\\Myfolder" get CreationDate /value
```

In this case, you will get something like

```
CreationDate=20160927171354.871547+120
```

Comment: That gives you time-last-written, not time-created as in the original code.

Comment: @Magoo, of course you are right, I saw `timestamp` and automatically switched my mind to `Last write time`, my fault.

Comment: Thanks @MCND. This solution works. I already used the `wmic` option in a batch file, but calling `wmic` for many folders is rather slow. Therefore I was opting to use `dir`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dir c:\folder\Myfolder\ /ad /t:c|findstr /L /e /c:" ."
```

should yield your desireed data

findstr `/L` literal `/e` at end `/c:" ."` constant string <kbd>Space</kbd>**<kbd>.</kbd>**

Comment: The `/L` option can't hurt, but it is redundant, given that `/C` defaults to a literal search. A comparable regex that works is `findstr /rc:" \.$"`.